# Can't login to Sanity via VSC terminal

Tags: node.js, sanity

? Login type Google

Opening browser at https://api.sanity.io/v1/auth/login/google?type=listen&uuid=2f9ed7bd06d956276b1709dc4c0ed24f&source=cli&label=Denzel-PC+%2F+win32

⠋ Waiting for browser login to complete... Press Ctrl + C to cancelnode:events:490
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell',
path: 'undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell',
spawnargs: [
'-NoProfile',
'-NonInteractive',
'–ExecutionPolicy',
'Bypass',
'-EncodedCommand',
'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBoAHQAdABwAHMAOgAvAC8AYQBwAGkALgBzAGEAbgBpAHQAeQAuAGkAbwAvAHYAMQAvAGEAdQB0AGgALwBsAG8AZwBpAG4ALwBnAG8AbwBnAGwAZQA/AHQAeQBwAGUAPQBsAGkAcwB0AGUAbgAmAHUAdQBpAGQAPQAyAGYAOQBlAGQANwBiAGQAMAA2AGQAOQA1ADYAMgA3ADYAYgAxADcAMAA5AGQAYwA0AGMAMABlAGQAMgA0AGYAJgBzAG8AdQByAGMAZQA9AGMAbABpACYAbABhAGIAZQBsAD0ARABlAG4AegBlAGwALQBQAEMAKwAlADIARgArAHcAaQBuADMAMgAiAA==

npm -y create sanity@latest

Answer (score 0):

**Use git bash** to provide credentials through the sanity login command. Any other terminals do not seem to be working.

*Source: https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/issues/4195*